# Column must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Tags: postgresql, count, group-by, sql-order-by, aggregate-functions

I'm updating a Qt software, to make it compatible with both SQLite and PostgreSQL.
I have a C++ method that is used to count elements of a given table with given clauses.

In SQLite, the following worked and gave me a number N (the count).

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_a 
INNER JOIN table_b AS
ON table_b.fk_table_a = table_a.id
WHERE table_a.start_date_time <> 0
ORDER BY table_a.creation_date_time DESC
```

With PostgreSQL (I'm using 9.3), I have the following error :

> ERROR:  column "table_a.creation_date_time" must appear in the
>   GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
>   LINE 5: ORDER BY
>   table_a.creation_date_time DESC

If I add, GROUP BY table_a.creation_date_time, it gives me a table with N rows.
I've read a lot of stuff about how different DBMS allow you to omit columns in the GROUP BY clause. Now, I'm just confused.

---

For those who are curious, the C++ method is:

```
static int count(const QString &table, const QString &clauses = QString(""))
{
    int success = -1;

    if (!table.isEmpty())
    {
        QString statement = QString("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ");
        statement.append(table);
        if (!clauses.isEmpty())
        {
            statement.append(" ").append(clauses)   ;
        }
        QSqlQuery query;
        if(!query.exec(statement))
        {
            qWarning() << query.lastError();
            qWarning() << statement;
        }
        else
        {
            if (query.isActive() && query.isSelect() && query.first())
            {
                bool ok = false;
                success = query.value(0).toInt(&ok);
                if (ok == false)
                {
                    success = -1;
                    return success;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return success;
}
```

Comment: Then SQLite AND MySQL are "relaxed".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just doing a `count(*)` on the table in order to get a single scalar-value result, then surely having the `order by` present is obsolete ?

*solution*

Remove the obsolete `order by` to get "standard" query behavior across multiple dbms

Comment: Wife: I'm thirsty. Me: Here's a glass of water. Wife: I didn't ask for a glass of water, I wanted you to empathize with me over my thirst issues. Me: Sorry baby, I'm all about fixing the problem

Comment: CampbellWell, I've seen that it works if I remove the `ORDER BY table_a.creation_date_time DESC`. The thing is that, when the method is called, the **clauses** parameter already contains the **GROUP BY** statement. Maybe I should remove this statement before each call to the method since, as you say, I only nead a single scalar-value everytime I call it.

Comment: bah. cowardly comment deletion @a_horse_with_no_name ;-)

Comment: I don't know what happened with @a_horse_with_no_name's comment. I saw it was already removed when I answered it. He quoted myself to tell me that MySQL is 'relaxed' in its way to handle the GROUP BY statement which is considered by some people to be an error or something like that.